# Shorthand for arrays: is there a literal syntax like {} or []?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

*What is the shorthand for array notation in PHP?*

I tried to use (doesn't work):

```
$list = {};
```

It will be perfect, if you give links on some information about other shorthands for PHP.

Comment: There are many functions that can be used to create arrays in special cases (e.g., str_split), but I assume that's not what you are talking about.

Comment: PHP hasn't. But phpreboot and pihipi provide experimental new syntax.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**Update:**
As of PHP 5.4.0 a [shortened syntax](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php) for declaring arrays has been introduced:

```
$list = [];
```

---

**Previous Answer:**

There isn't. Only `$list = array();` But you can just start adding elements.

```
<?php
$list[] = 1;
$list['myKey'] = 2;
$list[42] = 3;
```

It's perfectly OK as far as PHP is concerned. You won't even get a [E_NOTICE for undefined variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

> E_NOTICE level error is issued in case
>   of working with uninitialized
>   variables, however not in the case of
>   appending elements to the
>   uninitialized array.

As for shorthand methods, there are lots scattered all over. If you want to find them just read [The Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php).

Some examples, just for your amusement:

1. `$arr[]` shorthand for `array_push`.
2. The `foreach` construct
3. `echo $string1, $string2, $string3;`
4. Array concatenation with `+`
5. The existence of `elseif`
6. Variable embedding in strings, `$name = 'Jack'; echo "Hello $name";`

Comment: I've used PHP professionally for years, I had to ask a coworker what `$results[] = $row;` meant.

Comment: $results[] = $row; is actually a lot faster than array_push($results, $row)

Comment: After all this time, I thought `$var = [];` was introduced with PHP7. Had no idea it was as far back as 5.4 !

Answer (score 48):

**YES, it exists!!**

Extracted from another Stack Overflow question:

> The shortened syntax for arrays has been rediscussed, accepted, and
>   is now on the way be released with PHP 5.4

Usage:

```
$list = [];
```

Reference: [PHP 5.4 Short Hand for Arrays](https://coderwall.com/p/uftu7g)

Comment: For anyone who also made this mistake, use `=>` instead of `:` between keys and values!

Answer (score 39):

It is also possible to define content inside [ ] like so:

```
  $array = ['vaue1', 'value2', 'key3'=>['value3', 'value4']];
```

This will only work in php5.4 and above.

Comment: I think it is better to write 5.4 and above (in 5.6 it works). As a note it is the only working way to declare an array as a class constant (e.g. const x = ["a", "b"];) because the const x=array(....) doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

There are none as of PHP 5.3.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 4):

You can declare your array as follows:

```
$myArray1 = array(num1, num2, num3);
$myArray2 = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
$myArray3 = array( 'stringkey1'=>'stringvalue1', 'stringkey2'=>'stringvalue2');
$myArray4 = array( 'stringkey1'=>numValue1, 'stringkey2'=>numValue2);
$myArray5 = array( numkey1=>'stringvalue1', numkey2=>'stringvalue2');
$myArray6 = array( numkey1=>numValue1, numkey2=>numValue2);
```

You can have as many embedded arrays as you need.

Comment: This will produce notices about undefined constants.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to define an array in php is by the [`array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) language construct. PHP doesn't have a shorthand for array literals like some other languages do.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it was proposed and rejected by the community, so for now only syntax for arrays is [array()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

P.S. This is the old answer, now there is a syntax, check out other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I just explode strings into an array like so:

```
$array = explode(",","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10");
```