# 500 Internal Server Error on PHP calls

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, server-side, http-error, ajax-request

I have this problem when I request to a `php` file using `$.ajax` it always return me a 500 server error, but only when I upload the files to my server.
I use XAMPP on Windows 8.1 and in the `localhost` runs perfectly.

I've tried accesing the url of the `php` file directly and also gives me the same error.

**Ajax**:

```
function get_blog(reload_list){
    var $titulo, $texto, $response, $post, $post_list;
    var parameters = window.location.search;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/php/blog.php' + parameters,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "404"){
                $("#blog").html("404 El articulo que buscas no existe");
            } else {
                $response = data;
                $post_list = $response.post_list;
                $titulo = $response.post.titulo;
                $texto =  $response.post.texto;
                $("title#blog_title").html("IBR - " + $titulo);
                $("h3#blog_title").html($titulo);
                $("#blog_text").html($texto);

                if(reload_list){
                    for(i=0; i<=$post_list.length; i++){
                        $("#post_list").append($post_list[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors' 1); 

$l =  mysql_connect ( "localhost" , "myserver" , "mypass" ) or die("Error connecting:<BR><BR>".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db( "mydb" ) or die("Error getting db:<BR><BR>".mysql_error()); 
if(!isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $id = stripslashes($row['id']); 
    $titulo = stripslashes($row['titulo']); 
    $texto = stripslashes($row['texto']); 

    $post = [
            'id' => $id,
            'titulo' => $titulo,
            'texto' => $texto
    ];

}else{
    // echo $_GET['post_id'];
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=$post_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if(empty($row)){
        die("404");
    }
    $id = stripslashes($row['id']); 
    $titulo = stripslashes($row['titulo']); 
    $texto = stripslashes($row['texto']); 


    $post = [
            'id' => $id,
            'titulo' => $titulo,
            'texto' => $texto
    ];
}


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{

    $id = stripslashes($row['id']); 
    $titulo = stripslashes($row['titulo']); 

    $li = '<a class="text_decoration post_list_item" href="devocional.html?post_id='.$id.'"><li>'.$titulo.'</li></a>';

    $post_list[]= $li;
}

$response = [
    'post' => $post,
    'post_list' => $post_list
];

$json_response = json_encode($response);
print_r($json_response);
?>
```

Actually I don´t have access to my `error_log`. Also tried to see errors through the:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors' 1);
```

But the browser only shows a blank page. I have this same issue on a Facebook API call using the `PHP SDK` too. I really don't know what to do. Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: on the web server can you try to open the /php/blog.php with the actual GET parameters? so you can debug that way?

Comment: Are you running the same versions of PHP? Do you error logs have anything in them? I suspect your web server is running < 5.4. Here's a thread on my presumption, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271874/shorthand-for-arrays-is-there-a-literal-syntax-like-or.

Comment: @Ron I've done that still no geting any warnings apart the status code 500 on the network tab in the developer tools. I'm using Chrome 42.

Comment: @chris85 You're right in localhost i'm running php 5.6.3 and on server 5.2.17, like I said I don't have access to my error logs until tomorrow.

Comment: Won't need them. Change your arrays, should work after that I think. The shorthand arrays were introduced in 5.4 didnt exist in 5.2.

Comment: You're missing a coma on your `ini_set`: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); `

Comment: I've included your error in my answer as well @Ben. Both issues produced a 500 when tested on my 5.3 system, I missed the comma issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP didn't support the shorthand arrays as you're currently using until 5.4. http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Here's your updated code which should work and be forwards compatible with 5.6.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

$l =  mysql_connect ( "localhost" , "myserver" , "mypass" ) or die("Error connecting:<BR><BR>".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db( "mydb" ) or die("Error getting db:<BR><BR>".mysql_error()); 
if(!isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $id = stripslashes($row['id']); 
    $titulo = stripslashes($row['titulo']); 
    $texto = stripslashes($row['texto']); 

    $post = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'titulo' => $titulo,
            'texto' => $texto
    );

}else{
    // echo $_GET['post_id'];
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=$post_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if(empty($row)){
        die("404");
    }
    $id = stripslashes($row['id']); 
    $titulo = stripslashes($row['titulo']); 
    $texto = stripslashes($row['texto']); 


    $post = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'titulo' => $titulo,
            'texto' => $texto
    );
}


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{

    $id = stripslashes($row['id']); 
    $titulo = stripslashes($row['titulo']); 

    $li = '<a class="text_decoration post_list_item" href="devocional.html?post_id='.$id.'"><li>'.$titulo.'</li></a>';

    $post_list[]= $li;
}

$response = array(
    'post' => $post,
    'post_list' => $post_list
);

$json_response = json_encode($response);
print_r($json_response);
?>
```

Also, obligatory notes here...

1. Change your SQL drivers from mysql_ to mysqli or PDO.
2. Separate out your user input from your queries or at
   least use the mysql_real_escape_string (that function name might be
   inverted in order). Your currently open to SQL injections.

Comment: Well that's it. Thanks a lot I've been struggling this whole day.

Comment: One last question whats the best form of separating my user input from my queries. Literally I´ve been using PHP and MySQL only for a week.

Comment: With the mysql_ driver you are limited to the escape function or casting your data as an integer `$post_id = (int)$_GET['post_id'];`. With the mysqli and PDO drivers they support prepared statements. Here's a thread on the topic that goes into much more detail, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1