# Group values in PHP array

Tags: php

**Question:** How can I create group of values in a php array just like we can use the json format in javascript to group values.

**Example JS:**

`var jsarray = [{value1,value2},{value3,value4}]`

Is there something similar in PHP.

**I know I can use:**

```
$phparray = array(array(value1,value2), array(value3,value4));
```

But just in case something cleaner way is out there which I don't know about?

Comment: ``$phparray = [[$value1, $value2], [$value3, $value4]];`` available at version 5.4

Comment: Your JS example is broken...

Comment: @jmattheis php array short syntax works from PHP 5.4  (it's just a tip for those of us who still use 5.3)

Comment: @jmattheis thank you :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorthand for arrays: is there a literal syntax like {} or \[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271874/shorthand-for-arrays-is-there-a-literal-syntax-like-or)